# Store video sample in specific folder

Tags: android, android-camera, video-capture

I am trying to save video, created from custom application, to the specific folder inside DCIM folder, side by side to original camera folder.

```
    private fun recordVideo() {
    val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
    takeVideo.launch(intent)
}

private val takeVideo = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
) {
    if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Log.i(
            "VIDEO_RECORD_TAG ", "Video is available at ${
                it.data?.data?.let { it1 -> getRealPathFromURI(it1) }
            }"
        )

        saveMediaFile(
            it.data?.data?.let { it1 -> getRealPathFromURI(it1) }, "MyVideoName"
        )

    }
}

private fun saveMediaFile(filePath: String?, fileName: String) {
    filePath?.let {

        val values = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
            val mExtension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(filePath)
            put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(mExtension))
            put(MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES + "/${getString(R.string.app_name)}/")
            put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
        }

        val fileUri = contentResolver.insert(
            MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY),
            values
        )

        fileUri?.let {
            contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(fileUri, "w").use { descriptor ->
                descriptor?.let {
                    FileOutputStream(descriptor.fileDescriptor).use { out ->
                        val videoFile = File(filePath)
                        FileInputStream(videoFile).use { inputStream ->
                            val buf = ByteArray(8192)
                            while (true) {
                                val sz = inputStream.read(buf)
                                if (sz <= 0) break
                                out.write(buf, 0, sz)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            values.clear()
            values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
            contentResolver.update(fileUri, values, null, null)
        }
    }
}

private fun getRealPathFromURI(contentUri: Uri): String? {
    var cursor: Cursor? = null
    return try {
        val proj = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
        cursor = contentResolver.query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null)
        val columnIndex = cursor?.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
        cursor?.moveToFirst()
        columnIndex?.let { cursor?.getString(it) }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("TAG", "getRealPathFromURI Exception : $e")
        ""
    } finally {
        cursor?.close()
    }
}
```

Using this code, folder is created, video is stored as well, but in camera folder I have the same video with original name.
I would like to have only custom created folder with stored videos.

Any suggestion ?

Thanks

Comment: `trying to save video, created from custom application, to the specific folder inside DCIM folder,` No. You are not. `...RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES` That is no DCIM directory.

Comment: OK, what I need to do to get appropriate path ?

Comment: Environment.DIRECTORY_.........

Comment: OK, I doesn't solve the main problem which is that I have one video capture insite two folders, one is mine created from app, and the second one is in camera folder. 
I would like to avoid using camerax api, if it is possible.

Comment: I cannot follow you. Please mension full paths to begin with.

Comment: This is the full code. Above this mentioned code, is code for permissions and clickc etc etc.

So, the main goal is to open the app, open default camera, take a video, and save that video in custom folder in DCIM folder. WIth this code, after video capturing, I have created custom folder with captured video, and on basic camera folder i have the same video.
Two videos, two names of that video in two foders. I need only one video saved in  custom foder.